# Integer argument expected, got float error and float object cannot be interpreted as integer errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, pycharm

This is a code for virtual mouse using finger gestures. The above both errors are arising in the statements containing cv2.circle() and cv2.line(). I also tried using int(),round() and "//", but it still won't work. After I use int() or round(), the second error arises. I hope you can help me with this.

Thank you

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import wx
mouse = Controller()

app = wx.App(False)
(sx,sy) = wx.GetDisplaySize()
(camx,camy) = (320,240)

lowerBound=np.array([20, 80, 100])
upperBound=np.array([40,200,300])

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

kernelOpen = np.ones((5,5))
kernelClose = np.ones((20,20))
pinchFlag = 0

while True:
    ret, img = cam.read()
    img = cv2.resize(img,(340,220))

    #convert BGR to HSV
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # create the Mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV,lowerBound,upperBound)
    #morphology
    maskOpen = cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernelOpen)
    maskClose = cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpen,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose)

    maskFinal = maskClose
    conts,h = cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    if(len(conts)==2):
        if(pinchFlag==1):
            pinchFlag = 0
            mouse.release(Button.left)
        x1,y1,w1,h1 = cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
        x2,y2,w2,h2 = cv2.boundingRect(conts[1])
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x1+w1,y1+h1),(255,0,0),2)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x2,y2),(x2+w2,y2+h2),(255,0,0),2)
        cx1 = x1+w1/2
        cy1 = y1+h1/2
        cx2 = x2+w2/2
        cy2 = y2+h2/2
        cx = (cx1+cx2)/2
        cy = (cy1+cy2)/2
        cv2.line(img, (cx1,cy1),(cx2,cy2),(255,0,0),2)
        cv2.circle(img, (cx,cy),2,(0,0,255),2)
        mouseLoc = (sx-(cx*sx/camx), cy*sy/camy)
        mouse.position = mouseLoc
        while mouse.position != mouseLoc:
            pass
    elif(len(conts)==1):
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
        if(pinchFlag==0):
            pinchFlag = 1
            mouse.press(Button.left)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        cx = x+w/2
        cy = y+h/2
        cv2.circle(img,(cx,cy),(w+h)/4,(0,0,255),2)
        mouseLoc = (sx-(cx*sx/camx), cy*sy/camy)
        mouse.position = mouseLoc
        while mouse.position != mouseLoc:
            pass
    cv2.imshow("cam",img)
    cv2.waitKey(5)
```

The error keeps changing.
These are two of the errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/virtualmouse/main.py", line 49, in <module>
    cv2.line(img, (cx1,cy1),(cx2,cy2),(255,0,0),2)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-pz4stnv8\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/virtualmouse/main.py", line 63, in <module>
    cv2.circle(img,(cx,cy),(w+h)/4,(0,0,255),2)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-pz4stnv8\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Comment: cv2.rectangle's second and third parameters should be integers as well, can you please show the full error message ? :)

Comment: Thanks for adding the error message, have you tried adding int() to cx1, cy1, cx2 and cy2 ?

Comment: @MinaAbdEl-Massih. Better use `round` most likely

Comment: Any time you use `/`, you get a float. You should always truncate or round the result before passing it to the functions you are using. That includes box bounds.